# Modify (patch) meteor packages in a clean way - Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite, meteor-blaze

I am currently using the `accounts-ui-bootstrap-3-blaze` package in my Meteor application and I want to modify the `login_buttons_dropdown.html` file to just add an additional button in the drop down.
How can I patch this package in a 'clean' way? 
I already downloaded the package and embedded it manually via the `smart.json` file, but then I was not able to perform an automatic update via `mrt`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's only for the purposes of a single project then the easiest way would be not to use `mrt` at all, but put the package source code to the `packages` directory manually. You will also have to update the `.meteor/packages` file by yourself. One advantage of this solutions is that any updates to the package source code will be automatically detected by Meteor, so you can take advantage of the hot-code-push feature. This is particularly convenient while in the development process.

If you're planning to re-use your patches in other projects, then I would recommend forking the original repository. It should be quite easy as it will be probably hosted on github. You don't need to publish a package on the atmosphere to be able to install it with `mrt` command. The only thing you need to do is tell the meteorite to look for this particular package in your custom github repository, so:

```
"accounts-ui-bootstrap-3-blaze": {
  "git": "https://github.com/yourUsername/accounts-ui-bootstrap-3-blaze.git"
}
```

in your `smart.json` and you are good to go.